# varnish failed to stop and purge

Tags: magento, varnish, varnish-vcl

I installed varnish 4.0 on amazon linux (Linux 3.14.26-24.46.amzn1.x86_64)

```
rpm --nosignature -i https://repo.varnish-cache.org/redhat/varnish-4.0.el6.rpm
yum install varnish

[root@ip-172-31-10-??? /]# varnishd -V
varnishd (varnish-3.0.5 revision 1a89b1f)
Copyright (c) 2006 Verdens Gang AS
Copyright (c) 2006-2011 Varnish Software AS
```

It looks like Varnish can run, but i can't stop the varnish

```
[root@ip-172-31-10-??? /]# service varnish restart
Stopping Varnish Cache:                                    [FAILED]
Starting Varnish Cache:                                    [  OK  ]
```

It looks like I can stop the Varnish by following :

```
[root@ip-172-31-10-??? /]# pkill varnishd
```

But my magento website has always been cached, and I can't stop the varnish or purge the cache.

I try to fetch port, but nothing result:

```
[root@ip-172-31-10-233 /]# ps -ef | grep vanishd
root      2884  2464  0 02:33 pts/0    00:00:00 grep vanishd
```

I try to check the varnish by "varnishd -C -f /etc/sysconfig/Varnish", but nothing valuable info to  me.

/etc/sysconfig/Varnish is as following:

```
# Configuration file for varnish
#
# /etc/init.d/varnish expects the variable $DAEMON_OPTS to be set from this
# shell script fragment.
#

# Maximum number of open files (for ulimit -n)
NFILES=131072

# Locked shared memory (for ulimit -l)
# Default log size is 82MB + header
MEMLOCK=82000

# Maximum number of threads (for ulimit -u)
NPROCS="unlimited"

# Maximum size of corefile (for ulimit -c). Default in Fedora is 0
# DAEMON_COREFILE_LIMIT="unlimited"

# Set this to 1 to make init script reload try to switch vcl without restart.
# To make this work, you need to set the following variables
# explicit: VARNISH_VCL_CONF, VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS,
# VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT, VARNISH_SECRET_FILE, or in short,
# use Alternative 3, Advanced configuration, below
RELOAD_VCL=1

# This file contains 4 alternatives, please use only one.

## Alternative 1, Minimal configuration, no VCL
#
# Listen on port 6081, administration on localhost:6082, and forward to
# content server on localhost:8080.  Use a fixed-size cache file.
#
#DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081 \
#             -T localhost:6082 \
#             -b localhost:8080 \
#             -u varnish -g varnish \
#             -s file,/var/lib/varnish/varnish_storage.bin,1G"


## Alternative 2, Configuration with VCL
#
# Listen on port 6081, administration on localhost:6082, and forward to
# one content server selected by the vcl file, based on the request.  Use a
# fixed-size cache file.
#
#DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081 \
#             -T localhost:6082 \
#             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
#             -u varnish -g varnish \
#             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
#             -s file,/var/lib/varnish/varnish_storage.bin,1G"


## Alternative 3, Advanced configuration
#
# See varnishd(1) for more information.
#
# # Main configuration file. You probably want to change it :)
VARNISH_VCL_CONF=/etc/varnish/default.vcl
#
# # Default address and port to bind to
# # Blank address means all IPv4 and IPv6 interfaces, otherwise specify
# # a host name, an IPv4 dotted quad, or an IPv6 address in brackets.
# VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS=
#VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=6081
VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=80
#
# # Telnet admin interface listen address and port
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=6082
#
# # Shared secret file for admin interface
VARNISH_SECRET_FILE=/etc/varnish/secret
#
# # The minimum number of worker threads to start
VARNISH_MIN_THREADS=50
#
# # The Maximum number of worker threads to start
VARNISH_MAX_THREADS=1000
#
# # Idle timeout for worker threads
VARNISH_THREAD_TIMEOUT=120
#
# # Cache file location
VARNISH_STORAGE_FILE=/var/lib/varnish/varnish_storage.bin
#
# # Cache file size: in bytes, optionally using k / M / G / T suffix,
# # or in percentage of available disk space using the % suffix.
VARNISH_STORAGE_SIZE=1G
#
# # Backend storage specification
VARNISH_STORAGE="file,${VARNISH_STORAGE_FILE},${VARNISH_STORAGE_SIZE}"
#
# # Default TTL used when the backend does not specify one
VARNISH_TTL=120
#
# # DAEMON_OPTS is used by the init script.  If you add or remove options, make
# # sure you update this section, too.
DAEMON_OPTS="-a ${VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT} \
             -f ${VARNISH_VCL_CONF} \
             -T ${VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT} \
             -t ${VARNISH_TTL} \
             -w ${VARNISH_MIN_THREADS},${VARNISH_MAX_THREADS},${VARNISH_THREAD_TIMEOUT} \
             -p esi_syntax=0x2 \
             -u varnish -g varnish \
             -S ${VARNISH_SECRET_FILE} \
             -s ${VARNISH_STORAGE}"
#


## Alternative 4, Do It Yourself. See varnishd(1) for more information.
#
# DAEMON_OPTS=""
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [varnish failed to restart for VCC complier error: expected of 'acl', 'sub', 'backend',](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697241/varnish-failed-to-restart-for-vcc-complier-error-expected-of-acl-sub-bac)

Comment: Notice the varnish version differences, ie the rpm (and your text) indicate version 4.0, but you actually have 3.0.5 installed. maybe running multiple instances?